# Getting CORB issue while fetching while fetching data

Tags: c#, android, jquery, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am working with simple GET request using ajax which is working on the Postman also on the browser. But when I am trying to run it on Android device (hybrid app with Google Chrome browser) I am getting following warning.

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://test.getmydata.com/api/Test with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details

This what I think is the reason for not getting data. My server side is in 
C#. What should be the workaround for this ?

**edit**

Following is my request configuration :

```
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://test.getmydata.com/api/Test",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "bearer dOowSJJEJAF3_5A"
        }
      }
```

Comment: You need to add the appropriate headers on the response. If you don't have any control over the response, then there's not much you can do other than move your request to the server side: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I have edited my question with header part.

Comment: That's the request. You need to edit the *response*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : So I should add header like content-type": "application/json", in the response in server side